# Err when importing a dependency

Tags: java, maven, aws-iot

I am coming from a ruby programming background and I have started learning java. I absolutely fell in love with it. Right now I am trying to run the sample aws iot java sdk project but I keep getting this err.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

The import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature cannot be resolved
```

When I looked inside the maven dependency folder and navigated to `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` I did not find any class with `DeserializationFeature` as well as `ObjectMapper`

Any idea?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java-samples</artifactId>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-iot-device-sdk-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/iot/client/sample/odin/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludePackageNames>*.odin.*</excludePackageNames>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Show your pom.XML please

Comment: Maybe this dependency jar is too old ...

Comment: @Jens, updated.

Comment: @passion, could it be? I will try to update it. btw it was installed by default.

Comment: There is no dependency for Jackson.databind

Comment: dependency not added ...

Comment: @jens I assumed that it was not necessary since eclipse was adding it by default. My bad. Thanks for ur help though

Comment: eclipse do nothing by Default. Maybe that is a dependency of one of your other dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add dependency for  jackson-databind

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: it should be in jackson-databind-2.8.0.jar

Comment: ya it is . I was assuming that it would be on its separate file but it turns out that it is a method inside the databind class. thanks again mate

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm the version of the jar .... its part of jackson.databind.jar ... you might need the correct version

Comment: 2.7.4 , there are new version in the project`s site.